# Double integral from rectangular region to polar

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{3+2y-y^2}} \cos(x^2 + (y-1)^2)) dy dx $$ 
How do I go about solving this? I tried substituting $x$ and $y$ for $r\cos(\theta)$ and $r\sin(\theta)$ and $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$. I can't seem to figure it out. So far I believe it's a rectangular region.

Comment: It looks a bit weird... the inner integral is on $\cos(\ldots)\, dy$ but its upper limit is a function of $y$. That doesn't make sense to me.  Are you sure you've copied the expression correctly?

Comment: Yes this is an exam question, I tried for a long time, but couldn't come up with a solution. Hence I thought it is a rectangle.

Comment: If so, I'm afraid your exam question should go back to its author for correction.

Comment: @zena have you got by any chance the exam answer as a double-check for the solutions hereby?

Comment: Sorry, no. But I verified and this is a wrong question.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{3+2y-y^2}} \cos(x^2 + (y-1)^2)) dx dy $$

The change of variables in polar coordinates with center $(0,1)$ : 
$\quad \begin{cases}
x=r\cos(\theta)\\
y=1+r\sin(\theta) 
\end{cases}$ .

$$I=\int_{-\pi/2}^0\int_{0}^{2} \cos(r^2) rdr d\theta $$
$$I=\int_{0}^2\cos(r^2) rdr \int_{-\pi/2}^0 d\theta $$
$$I=\left(\frac12\sin(2^2)\right)\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
$$I=\frac{\pi}{4}\sin(4)$$

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake IT IS DY DX not the other way around, I fixed the question.

Comment: The first writing of the integral with $dxdy$ was correct. Now, with $dydx$ is is not possible to integrate the inner integral with respect to $y$ because the bound is a function of $y$. In the first writing the integration versus $x$ was possible because the bound is not function of $x$. You should correct again and come back to the previous writing. In fact it doesn't matter since everybody understand what is the double integration to perform.

Comment: This was an exam question actually, with dy dx.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Obviously $y$ cannot varies from $0$ to $\sqrt{3+2y-y^2}$ . The student must understand that this cannot be the correct boundary.  As a consequence there is no other possibility that   $-1<y<1$ and $0<x<\sqrt{3+2y-y^2}$ as in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly NOT a rectangle. y goes from -1 to 1 and, for each y, x goes from 0 to $x= \sqrt{3+ 2y- y^2}$.  Squaring both side, $x^2= 3+ 2y+ y^2$.  $x^2- y^2- 2y= 3$, $x^2- y^2- 2y- 1= 2$.  $x^2- (y+ 1)^2= 2$.  That is a hyperbola with center at (0, -1).

Comment: It is a circle $x^2+(y-1)^2=4$ .

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake IT IS DY DX not the other way around, I fixed the question.

Answer (score -1):

$$\int_0^{-\frac{3\pi}{2}}\int_0^2\cos\left(r^2\left(\cos^2\theta\right)\ +\left(r\left(\sin\theta\right)-1\right)^2\right)rdrd\theta$$

This will do it!